# Get the MVC controller name in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a *Jquery* CRUD function; which is called from several Controllers actions.
Is there any way to find out which contoller is tiggering that function.

For Example; function call from View:

```
$('a.Edit-Icon').live("click", function (event) { 
  editDialog(this, event, '#_List'); 
});
```

Function parameters:

```
function editDialog(tag, event, target,value)
{
  ------
  // How to get the Controller name ???????????

}
```

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: The way I've been doing stuff like this is to put the partial url information in a data- attribute from the model when I build the view that I can read later using JQuery.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can get controller's name in javascript this way using razor:

```
var controllerName = '@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString()';
```

Or

```
var controllerName='@HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()';
```

**Update**:

You can also get controller's name this way:

```
var controllerName = '@ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue';
```