# Trying to get my controller and action name in a javascript file

Tags: javascript, controller

I'm looking at the SO link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450401/get-the-mvc-controller-name-in-javascript-function) and the anser that is given is

```
var controllerName = '@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString()';
```

but this doesn't seem to return anything in my javascript file. It just shows the value as the string '@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString()' it doesn't compute the name.

Answer (score 1):

I had to put this in my view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var controllerName = '@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString()';
    var actionName = '@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString()';
</script>
```

I couldn't just read it in my javascript file. Now the two variables are accessable in my JS file